# Invoke-Expression conda powershell prompt

Tags: anaconda

I installed Anaconda 4.7.11 and have a problem now.
When I started the conda prompt(run as administrator or not), it throws me a trouble.

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:1523
+ ... n\Scripts;D:\python;D:\python;D:\workspace_py;"C:\WINDOWS\system32;""
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'C:\WINDOWS\system32' in expression or statement.
At D:\Anaconda\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 char:9
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

So i looked at the psm1 and the line is

```
 begin {
        $OldPath = Add-Sys-Prefix-To-Path;
        If ($Stack) {
            $activateCommand = (& $Env:CONDA_EXE $Env:_CE_M $Env:_CE_CONDA shell.powershell activate --stack $Name | Out-String);
        } Else {
            $activateCommand = (& $Env:CONDA_EXE $Env:_CE_M $Env:_CE_CONDA shell.powershell activate $Name | Out-String);
        }
        $Env:PATH = $OldPath;

        Write-Verbose "[conda shell.powershell activate $Name]`n$activateCommand";
        Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
    }
```

and the 101 is  Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;

I can't know what the problem is. Is there anyone who had the same problem and fixed it?

Comment: and the (base) doesn't come up.

Comment: "C:\WINDOWS\system32;"- why has this got double quotes?That might be the problem.

Comment: Man. I was such a fool. Thanks a lot. bless you.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, but I don't know anything about powershell.  What specific action can I take to correct the problem?  Sorry for my ignorance.