# Conda activate Invoke-Expression error

Tags: command-line, powershell

In a project, I noticed that conda was not activated in my PowerShell, Whenever I attempt to run the

```
conda activate base
```

command I get the following set of errors;

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:295
+ ... conda3\condabin;C:\Python310\Scripts;C:\Python310;"C:\Program Files\n ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'C:\Program' in expression or statement.
At C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:101 char:9
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

A previous [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1478950/invoke-expression-conda-powershell-prompt) has a very similar question, with one of the comments informing me to check the double quotes on C:\Program files...

I couldn't understand which file this has occurred, A glance through the .psm1 file informed under the unexpected token error does not show any of the above-mentioned paths.

Comment: that looks like a path statement - a list of paths to search for stuff. i suspect that you have a missing/extra quote - OR that you have one of those nasty typographical quotes where you otta have a simple straight [not curved] quote.

Answer (score 1):

I find that it has nothing to do with the Conda.psm1 despite the error message, but rather on the format of our path variable.

What works for me (Windows):

1. Go to your Control Panel and then to the Advanced System Setting
2. Go to the advanced tab of the system properties, you should see the 'Environment Variables' button, click that
3. You should be able to find a variable called 'Path' in the top box user variable
4. Double-click on that to edit your path statement to get rid of any unnecessary quotation or double semicolon (whatever is causing your error).
5. Make sure to close all terminals before you try to 'conda activate' again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and was able to solve it by inspecting the Windows PATH variables.

[Offending quote in user variable PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38I8T.png)
In Windows 10:

1. in PowerShell, type `$Env:Path`
2. inspect the output for unexpected quotes or other odd characters
3. open "Edit the system environment variables" from Control Panel (or search for "environ" using the windows search
4. PATH may be present in the top and bottom sections - User variables, System variables
5. in my case, I had pasted a quoted path in user variables
6. remove the quotes or offending characters
7. open PowerShell again (no errors should appear now)
8. run `conda activate base` if it does not happen automatically (no errors should appear)

Cause:
After running the CUDA 11.8 installer on Windows 10, it informed me that it was unable to update the PATH variable due to it being the maximum length. I manually edited the PATH and then noticed Powershell was producing errors related to conda trying to activate base. I must have pasted a quoted string in the user variables PATH.